# Adding new row from column

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table

```
emp checking    saving
a   100         500
a   200         1000
c   300         2000
d   300         200
d   100         50
```

I need to create a second row from saving column so I will need this result

```
emp    checking
a      100
a      500
a      200
a      1000
c      300
c      2000
d      300
d      200
d      100
d      50
```

I tried this query

```
select t.emp, v.checking, v.saving
from Table1 t
cross apply (values
                 (1, checking, null),
                 (2, null, saving)
            ) v (n, checking, saving)
order by T.emp, v.n;
```

and I get this

```
emp checking    saving
a   200 NULL
a   100 NULL
a   NULL    500
a   NULL    1000
c   300 NULL
c   NULL    2000
d   300 NULL
d   100 NULL
d   NULL    50
d   NULL    200
```

Can someone see what went wrong and correct it. Thanks

I need to bring this back cause if I use this query

```
select emp, checking
from  table1
union all
select emp, saving
from  table1
order by emp
```

then I get this

```
emp checking
a   100
a   200
a   500
a   1000
c   2000
c   300
d   300
d   100
d   200
d   50
```

and still not correct. Please if you have better idea. Thank you

Comment: I suggest to `UNION` of two simple `SELECT` statements with `ORDER BY` at the end (if required).

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky - OP already provided enough. Your requirements are super overkill.

Comment: Can I delete this question?

Comment: Yes, you sure can.

Comment: Your `UNION ALL` query looks correct? You can still use a `CROSS APPLY`, just do it like this `cross apply (values (checking), (saving)) v (checking)`

Comment: Please look at the sample result so each row should have saving column next to next row  a 100 (checking) and next row 500 (saving) but not 200

Comment: @Dale K.  If I used UNION ALL then it will not work right                                                                                    emp    checking
a      100
a      200                                                                                                                 should                                                                                                               emp    checking
a      100
a      500

Comment: Oh the ordering is not correct - you need to be clear about the order it needs to be in - you didn't mention that anywhere.

Comment: @ Dale K My apologize.

Comment: @Tsang please [edit] your question now so that its clear for future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (emp CHAR(1), checking INT, saving INT);
INSERT @tbl (emp, checking, saving) VALUES
('a', 100, 500 ),
('a', 200, 1000),
('c', 300, 2000),
('d', 300, 200 ),
('d', 100, 50  );
-- DDL and sample data population, start

SELECT t.emp, v.checking
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
                (checking),
                (saving)
            ) AS v (checking)
ORDER BY t.emp;
```

**Output**

| emp | checking |
| --- | --- |
| a | 100 |
| a | 500 |
| a | 200 |
| a | 1000 |
| c | 300 |
| c | 2000 |
| d | 300 |
| d | 200 |
| d | 100 |
| d | 50 |

Comment: Just curious, is a `CROSS APPLY` guaranteed to always be ordered in the order calculated?

Comment: Just testing with a bigger data set will reveal it

Comment: Any table suppose to have a primary key. This exactly what is missing here

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Yitzhak's excellent answer, and assuming you have some form of `id` per row (because otherwise you cannot ensure the order you desire), I would do the following to ensure you get the exact order you want. While its possible `CROSS APPLY` will always be ordered correctly, in SQL its usually best to explicitly order a dataset if the order is important.

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id int, emp char(1), checking int, saving int);

INSERT @tbl (id, emp, checking, saving)
VALUES
(1, 'a', 100, 500),
(2, 'a', 200, 1000),
(3, 'c', 300, 2000),
(4, 'd', 300, 200),
(5, 'd', 100, 50);

SELECT t.emp, v.checking
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
    (checking, 0),
    (saving, 1)
) AS v (checking, orderby)
ORDER BY t.emp, t.id, v.orderBy;
```

Comment: Cool, another great point to validate data.